# Ambari server exits with no error message in the log

Tags: hadoop

I have downloaded Hortonworks Data Platform 2.3.0 and installed it on Centos7.  The installation was successful.

When starting the server the following messages are displayed:

```
[root@sparkperf-5360 apps]# ambari-server start
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.7
Starting ambari-server
Ambari Server running with administrator privileges.
Organizing resource files at /var/lib/ambari-server/resources...
Server PID at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid
Server out at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out
Server log at: /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log
Waiting for server start....................
ERROR: Exiting with exit code -1.

REASON: Ambari Server java process died with exitcode 255. 
Check /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.out for more information
```

The server log however does not have any errors in it. Here is an excerpt:

```
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2015-08-26 00:43:28.631--ServerSession(324035818)--The reference column name [resource_type_id] mapped on the element [field permissions] does not correspond to a valid id or basic field/column on the mapping reference. Will use referenced column name as provided.
[EL Info]: 2015-08-26 00:43:30.073--ServerSession(324035818)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-08-26 00:43:30.331--ServerSession(324035818)--file:/usr/lib/ambari-server/ambari-server-2.1.0.1470.jar_ambari-server_url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/ambari_user=ambari login successful
Aug 26, 2015 12:43:32 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.apache.ambari.server.api.rest
  org.apache.ambari.server.api.services
  org.apache.ambari.eventdb.webservice
  org.apache.ambari.server.api
Aug 26, 2015 12:43:34 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.PersistKeyValueService
  class org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.ClusterService
  class org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.TargetClusterService

 ..

  Aug 26, 2015 12:43:34 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class org.apache.ambari.eventdb.webservice.JAXBContextResolver
  class org.apache.ambari.server.api.GsonJsonProvider
Aug 26, 2015 12:43:34 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM'
Aug 26, 2015 12:43:34 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BlueprintService.getBlueprints(java.lang.String,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo), should not consume any entity.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BlueprintService.getBlueprint(java.lang.String,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,java.lang.String), should not consume any entity.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.RequestService.getRequests(java.lang.String,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo), should not consume any entity.
 .. and many more similar WARNING's

INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.apache.ambari.server.resources.api.rest
Aug 26, 2015 12:43:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.apache.ambari.server.resources.api.rest.GetResource
Aug 26, 2015 12:43:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Aug 26, 2015 12:43:35 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM'
```

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Well the errors **do** show up - but in the server **log** instead of the **.out** file as described in the error message.

It is an easily resolveable item: need to set a different jetty port:

```
26 Aug 2015 00:43:35,377  WARN [main] AbstractLifeCycle:204 - 
FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```